# Determine who is opening an Excel file on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I understand "Environ" can identify who opens the file, but I do not know how to write the code for it.

I found one answer that emails via Outlook when a file is opened, but ideally it would be logged with the person's name and time stamped in a hidden tab in the worksheet or some other file.  Since the user will not be making edits to the file and/or saving it I don't know if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you can use. Open VBE (Alt+F11) double click on the "ThisWorkbook" over in the Project window for your spreadsheet and then paste this in.

```
Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'When the worksheet opens, this will write the computer username
    '   and the date and time to a worksheet of your choice
    '   just change that "YourHiddenSheetNameHere" to the name of your
    '   hidden tab

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim hiddenSheet As Worksheet

    Set hiddenSheet = Sheets("YourHiddenSheetNAmeHere")
    lastRow = hiddenSheet.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row

    hiddenSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = ReturnUserName
    hiddenSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Now()


End Function

Function ReturnUserName() As String
     ' returns the NT Domain User Name
    Dim rString As String * 255, sLen As Long, tString As String
    tString = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    sLen = GetUserName(rString, 255)
    sLen = InStr(1, rString, Chr(0))
    If sLen > 0 Then
        tString = Left(rString, sLen - 1)
    Else
        tString = rString
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReturnUserName = UCase(Trim(tString))
End Function
```

This will fire every time someone opens the workbook saving the username they used to log into the computer as well as the date and time. Saving to whichever tab you stick in there. You'll need to save the workbook with `.xlsm` instead of `.xlsx` since it will be a macro-enabled book.